# c++ regex search pattern not found

Tags: c++, regex

Following the example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/) I wrote following code:

```
using namespace std::regex_constants;
std::string str("{trol,asdfsad},{safsa, aaaaa,aaaaadfs}");
std::smatch m;
std::regex r("\\{(.*)\\}");   // matches anything between {}

std::cout << "Initiating search..." << std::endl;
while (std::regex_search(str, m, r)) {
    for (auto x : m) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    str = m.suffix().str();
}
```

But to my surprise, it doesn't find anything at all which I fail to understand. I would understand if the regex matches whole string since `.*` is greedy but nothing at all? What am I doing wrong here?

To be clear - I know that regexes are not suitable for Parsing BUT I won't deal with more levels of bracket nesting and therefore I find usage of regexes good enough.

Comment: Why you are trying to use `basic grammar` instead of default ECMAScript?

Comment: I wasn't really sure what ECMAScript is, so I thought I would stick with good old POSIX. But it doesn't really matter, I don't find anything even with ECMAScript... Already deleted the basic parameter though...

Comment: Now that you've removed `basic` (n.b. parentheses are literal in basic regex unless you escape them) it matches the whole string with gcc 4.9.

Comment: That is probably the problem. I compiled it with gcc 4.8.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use basic posix syntax, your regex should be

```
{\\(.*\\)}
```

If you want to use default ECMAScript, your regex should be

```
\\{(.*)\\}
```

with clang and libc++ or with gcc 4.9+ (since only it fully support regex) your code give:

```
Initiating search...
{trol,asdfsad},{safsa, aaaaa,aaaaadfs} trol,asdfsad},{safsa, aaaaa,aaaaadfs
```

[Live example on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b56ad8e70109553c)

Comment: I have compiled the code with g++ v4.8 which I suppose causes the problem. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Eventually it turned out to really be problem with gcc version so I finally got it working using boost::regex library and following code:

```
std::string str("{trol,asdfsad},{safsa,aaaaa,aaaaadfs}");
boost::regex rex("\\{(.*?)\\}", boost::regex_constants::perl);
boost::smatch result;

while (boost::regex_search(str, result, rex)) {
    for (uint i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << result[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    str = result.suffix().str();
}
```